# Difference vs Variation

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, word-difference

> ***Variations*** in the skeletal systems of two early types of human are illustrated in this diagram.

[image]

The question is that is there any particular purpose of being used the word ***variation*** instead of ***difference*** in this context. Don't they mean nearly the same thing?

Comment: *Variation, variety, vary* etc. all imply ***change*** (from an original form) - in your context, evolutionary changes (from some common ancestral form). You might say that **A**, **ɑ**, and **a** are ***variations*** of a single underlying letter, whereas **A** and **X**, for example, are simply ***different*** letters.

Comment: "Variation" is a *kind* of difference, so the author could have written "difference" with little change in meaning.  "Variation" is a more precise word (as Peter defines in his answer).

Comment: @FumbleFingers is the word *variation* used to refer to the comparison between the two skeletal systems or differences only one system ?

Comment: There's no particular reason why your introductory text shouldn't have been ***Differences between** the skeletal systems of two early types of human...* But you can't have differences or variations unless you're comparing at least two different things (skeletons, skeletal systems, or whatever). I'm simply saying that there can be a slight difference (usually not *slight variation*) between the *nuances* conveyed by the two words. If you've got variations, this usually implies things *vary from some underlying form*.

Comment: let's say, australopithecus afarensis had heavier body while homo erectus was slimmer. So could we say that this is the *variation* between the 2 skeletal systems?

Answer (score 2):

A variation is a *change* from a *model* or *standard*, a **difference** is a *measure* of the **variation**

In mathematics, the **difference** between *two numbers* is the subtractive result, whereas the **variation** is how much/often the **differences** occur in a *population.*

> **Variations** create **differences** between an original and offshoots.

Comment: it's hard to understand your point unless you support it with some simple  examples.